# Unable to start django site

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to run my django application/site by using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But the command line just does not show any output.

I have selected the python env as the interpreter already but still, nothing happens

[image]

Comment: Check that you are running the command from the folder where manage.py lives.

Comment: yup, but still nothing happens

Comment: what happens when you type python only? Did you do pip install django

Comment: when i type python, it opens up windows store for some reason. Yes i have pip install django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is might be comıng from your terminal type.

Go to Powershell menu in terminal and click *Select Default Shell* and then select **Command Prompt** from the menu appears in top which says Select your preferred terminal shell. Then Click **+** in terminal

When your terminal looks like this,

[image]

try again

```
      python manage.py runserver
```